# Jython Installation and Running (Beginner Issues)

Tags: java, installation, jython, launch, jython-2.5

I am having some serious trouble installing and running Jython. I am completely new to how jython runs, so I am pretty lost. I have downloaded Jython 2.5.3 and java jre 1.8.0_25. I believe I have succesfully run the jython.jar file using this command in cmd:

```
C:\java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java -jar C:\jython2.5.3\jython.jar
```

I have beginner-intermediate (closer to beginner) knowledge of programming in jython, but that is on a computer with jython already installed. My main problem is being able to run jython so I can see the actual function/program area where you would type out your functions then run them. I appreciate any help someone can give.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're encountering? Is there an error being displayed?

Comment: I just don't know how to run the program. I thought there would be an executable, so I just don't get how to start Jython. Basically, my problem is I'm being stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command is exactly how you run Jython, and without providing any additional arguments, the Jython interpreter will start (where you can type out functions and run them).

If you want to run Jython with a single command, there should be a `jython.bat` file located somewhere under the Jython installation directory. Jython does not have a true executable because it is run through Java. The `jython.bat` file is the closest you'll get to an executable because it is a batch script which runs the `jython.jar` file using a command nearly identical to yours with Java. `jython.bat` should be located at one of the following locations:

```
C:\jython2.5.3\jython.bat
C:\jython2.5.3\bin\jython.bat
```

NOTE: The `jython.bat` file requires a standard Java installation.

Comment: This worked, it turned out Java was in the wrong place. Thanks for the help.